# Dataflow read from a topic PubSub and write to Bigquery (multiples tables)

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

there is someone who has used DynamicDestination in Dataflow who has a simple and described example. I got bored of seeing the example teleport in git (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/DLPTextToBigQueryStreaming.java) , it hurts me to be a novice in apache Beam. By the way, what I need to do is read a message from Pubsub and through a Dataflow job write to different destinations (tables) in BigQuery dataset. I have a custom project that works perfect for a Bigquery table but the Pubsub topic will contain multiple destinations from the same dataset. Also, the message is in JSON format and contains a field with the name of the destination table.

This is my most representative code

```
TopicToBigQueryOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(TopicToBigQueryOptions.class);
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
p.apply(Constants.READ_PUBSUB, PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription(options.getInputSubscription()))
         .apply(Constants.LINE_TO_CHAMP, new PubSubToTableRowTransform())
         .apply(Constants.WRITE_CHAMPBAN, BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                .to(options.getTableStagingFileLines())
                .withSchema(AmplaChangeLogSchema.getTableSchema())
                .withCreateDisposition(CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
             .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

Any suggest?

Best regards

Comment: Look at this [example](https://github.com/ryanmcdowell/dataflow-bigquery-dynamic-destinations), that might be relevant for the current use case.

Comment: Do you need to write each pubsub message content in only one table (which can change accroding with the pubsub message content)? Or do you need to write in several table the same pubsub message?

Comment: Correct each message corresponds to a table, but I have 25 different types of messages @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: @mk_sta The example is pretty close to what I need, unfortunately that example needs to set tableNameAttr from the producer (kafka in my case), I couldn't get that. In my case I have an attribute called TableName in the JSON paylod.

Comment: The example is exactly what you need. Here the table name is discovered based on PubSub attribute. But you can add preproccessing into the `getTableDestination` function to extract the PubSub message payload, parse it as you want and to get the correct value!

Comment: That function ?    static TableDestination getTableDestination(
      ValueInSingleWindow<PubsubMessage> value,
      String tableNameAttr,
      String outputProject,
      String outputDataset)

What if I also need to update and delete records?
According to what is sent from onpremises (Kafka)

Comment: Works fine for new records, but now i need update and delete too :(

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, the original author ([@Ryan McDowell](https://github.com/ryanmcdowell)) is explaining pretty the same user [scenario](https://github.com/ryanmcdowell/dataflow-bigquery-dynamic-destinations), consuming the JSON payloads from within GCP Pub/Sub messaging queue, performing dynamic routing to Bigquery tables, extracting certain table name throughout a specific attribute from Pub/Sub message.

In the pipeline from the [example](https://github.com/ryanmcdowell/dataflow-bigquery-dynamic-destinations/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pso/pipeline/PubsubToBigQueryDynamicDestinations.java), we see `getTableDestination()` method, inherited from [DynamicDestinations](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/DynamicDestinations.html) class, that is used to extract particular attribute(`tableNameAttr`) from within the message which contains Bigquery table name, finally identifying destination object [TableDestination()](https://github.com/ryanmcdowell/dataflow-bigquery-dynamic-destinations/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pso/pipeline/PubsubToBigQueryDynamicDestinations.java#L193).

Comment: Yes, now i need update and delete too, that's more complicated.

Comment: I guess this is out of context for the genuine question, consider to create a separate thread. However, if you find the above solution useful then you can accept/up vote it, thus this would be helpful for the further contributors research.